# Colorpicker not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So right now, I can dynamically create elements (2 rows of 12 blocks) and when I click on an individual block, I can change the color of it as well.

However, I am having one problem. When I click on a block to have its color changed, the color picker will pop up beside it, no issues at all. When I add a new set of rows and try to color the same block number, it will replace the color of the block from the previous row.

For example, if I color the 12th block in the first row, then add 2 new sets of rows and click on the same block in the second set, it will act as if I'm clicking on the previous set's block. I am using https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ as my colorPicker

Here is a link to what I have done so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwBRmw

```
var id_num = 1;
var picker = null;
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
      $parent.after($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;

    } else {
      $parent.before($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;
    }
});   
});


$(".container").on("click", "a", function(e) {
var self = this;
console.log(this.id)
console.log(this)

    $(self).spectrum({
      color: "#f00",
      change: function(color) {
          $(self).css('background-color',color.toHexString());
      }
  });

e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are cloning elements which already have the colorpicker events bound.

EDIT: I think I've managed to work around the problem by changing your use of jQuery's `clone()`. If you tell it to clone without including events (omitting the first parameter to `clone()` which defaults to `false`, the DOM objects will be created without the colorpicker pointing at the old ones.

[Here's an example](http://codepen.io/bbodien/pen/xEqVpw?editors=0010#0) that I think is doing what you are looking for. I've just removed the `true` params for `clone()`. No changes to HTML or CSS.

Comment: but isn't it already in a function? The listener waits before I click on the element before running the function with the spectrum code in it